# Formulation of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Given:
>   $$
> z= A \exp(pt) \sin(px)
> $$
>   where $A,p$ are arbitrary constants to be eliminated.
>   Find the associated PDE.

If I am not wrong since there are 2 constants and 2 independent variables we must get a 1st order PDE which is unique right?

My book gives the answer in the form of a second order PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that taking a $t$-derivative adds a factor of $p$, and $x$-derivative also flips between sine and cosine, so the relation we are seeking will deal with 2 derivatives, since that will flip the sine twice back into the sine. We get
$$
z_{tt} = p^2z \quad \text{and} \quad z_{xx} = -p^2z,
$$
so the PDE you seek is $$z_{tt} + z_{xx} = 0.$$

Comment: I understand the reason of taking second derivative when it comes to simplifying the solution. However shouldn't 2 independent variables (and 2 constants) imply that we will have a 1st order PDE?

Comment: @AJ_ not necessarily

Comment: So then how does it work for PDE? For ODEs it was quite well defined!

Comment: Also the same book does say "When the number of arbitrary constants is equal to the number of independent variables then it shall give rise to a UNIQUE PDE of ORDER 1"

Comment: @AJ_ what's the unique pde for $u(x,t)=Ap$?